# IntelliTrace Standalone Collector OutputPath empty

Tags: c#, intellitrace, historical-debugging

We've installed the IntelliTrace Standalone Collector on an IIS web server in our UAT environment. We followed the instructions detailed in this MSDN technical article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh398365(v=vs.110).aspx.

However, when we issue the "Start-IntelliTraceCollection" command (described in this section of the MSDN tech article - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh398365(v=vs.110).aspx#BKMK_Collect_Data_from_IIS_Application_Pools) the *OutputPath* is empty and no .iTrace file is generated.

Any ideas on what the problem is and how it can be resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *OuputPath* is set with a value once there is activity in the App Pool associated with the website in IIS. In other words you need to perform an action on the website in order for IntelliTrace to start recording.

This seems obvious now but it was not stated clearly in any tutorial I read on the web about IntelliTrace. Our situation was complicated by the fact that there are 4 IIS web servers in the the environment and these are load balanced. Therefore it is difficult to know which IIS web server is receiving the http request.